# What is the best format for transferring RTFs from a server to a local RTF editor?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I know that I can use a BLOB or an XML file, but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, or if either of these are the correct way of doing this. The user should be able to edit their file online and then save it onto the server, and at any time get the file back into the editor and continue editing that file (similar to that of Google Drive). Any ideas? We are using Spring Framework and controllers for our site. We are using a MongoDB for file storage (files are stored on the server, file paths are stored on the MongoDB).

Comment: RTF is a format. Why would you need another format? I don't really get the question.

Comment: @JBNizet I know RTF is a format, but I dont know if it is possible to transfer RTF files directly from a server to a front end RTF editor without converting to some sort of Mark-Up file type. (Note: I am using TinyMCE Editor)

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You send a HTTP request to the server, which sends back the content of the RTF file, with the appropriate content-type header. Don't you ever download PDF, zip, txt, mp3 or any other kind of files on the web? Why would RTF be any different?

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not sure why an RTF would be different- I just did not know if I could directly send RTFs through HTTP requests.... thanks! I will look into it.

Comment: @JBNizet From what I understand, I can return the content of the RTF and use an RTF to HTML parser to put the contents of the RTF back into the TinyMCE Editor. When saving/downloading, I can convert from HTML to RTF with another parser. Does this sound viable?